# Svelte SSR (рендеринг на стороне сервера)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8, ssr, svelte

Решил попробовать связку для создания сайта: `laravel` + `svelte` + `sveltestrap`. До сего момента со `svelte` дело не имел, только знакомлюсь. Начальная инфа меня, скажем так, вдохновила. Но и возникли вопросы ...

Во многих мануалах написано, что генерация содержимого страницы на стороне клиента резко снижает показатели SEO. Но пишут, мол есть выход - использование SSR (server side rendering).

**Собственно, вопросы**

1. Что должно быть на хостинге дополнительно к `web-сервер` + `php` + `database`, чтобы мочь использовать SSR?
2. "Кто" именно осуществляет SSR? Cофтина `node.js` у провайдера или что-то иное?

Comment: SSR - это Ваш же сервер, на который выплевывает уже отрендеренную страницу и продолжает использовать скрипты. Собственно, хостить Вы будете всё вместе. Для Svelte можете использовать (https://kit.svelte.dev/)[Svelte kit] для построения SSR. Это уже фреймворк готовый, который запускаете в билде, и будет работать всё как надо без танцев с бубном.

Comment: Насчет генерации на стороне клиента - да, но в последнее время зависимость от отрендеренной страницы сильно снижается, гугл и яндекс вводят пререндер JS на страницах у поисковых ботов

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, а вы можете ответить на мои вопросы, заданные "в вопросе"?

Comment: Смотря какие ответы Вы хотите получить. Выше в комментариях есть ответы на эти вопросы. 1. Сервер фронта + прокси к основному веб-серверу. 2. Вы - сервер фронта, ещё раз, svelte kit изучите. SSR - это не что-то магическое, это просто отрендеренный клиент на сервере через v8.

Comment: Так у меня изначально и был вопрос - какой софт на стороне сервера рендерит, как вы пишите - через v8? На сервере моего хостера, кроме php, который бы там исполнялся - больше ничего нет.  Как происходит рендеринг на сервере через v8?

Comment: Так Вы ничего и не сделаете без нормальной машины, VDS или Dedicated. Shared-хостинг ничего Вам не даст. Опять же, если бы немного погуглили, то нашли бы всё спокойно. JS на сервере – Node.js, сами же ответили себе. Больше Вам ничего не нужно, кроме понимания, как это работает, сейчас у Вас, по всей видимости, этого понимания нет. И вопрос у Вас не так задан.

Comment: Владимир, и тем не менее, я получил от Вас нужный мне ответ :-) Спасибо.